# Find : $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+\sin x-\cos x+\log(1-x))}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Using squeeze theorem  find the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+\sin x-\cos x+\log(1-x))}{x^3}$$

My approach :

I may only use the squeeze theorem. Please guide how to use this to solve the below question

Suppose we have inequality :

$h(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x) $

$ \lim_{x\to c} h(x) \leq \lim_{x\to c} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to c} g(x) $

$ \lim_{x\to c} h(x) \leq L \leq \lim_{x\to c} g(x) $

Comment: you can use the taylor expantion as $x$ goes to zero

Comment: I think you should try upper and lower bounds for $\log (1-x) $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Looking at taylor expansion of each functions, you can find upper and lower polynomial-type estimation for each functions on top.  For example

$$  x - \frac{x^3}{6}  \leq \sin(x) \leq x - \frac{x^3}{6} +\frac{x^5}{5 !} $$

for all $x$ close to $0$.  You do this for each functions on top (at least up to the term $x^3$) then you can find squeezers.

Comment: but we need to use sandwich theorem / squeeze theorem to solve this

Comment: @ sultan Ok I didn't get your purpose by saying , I have only ....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can also apply the De l'Hopital's rule repeatedly:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos x+\sin x +\log (1-x)}{x^3}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x+\sin x -\frac{1}{1-x}}{3x^2}=...
$$

Comment: OP wants to solve this problem only by squeeze theorem !

Answer (score 0):

$sinx=x-{x^3}/{6}+o(x^3)$

$cosx=1-x^2/2+o(x^3)$

$log(1-x)=-x-x^2/2-x^3/3+o(x^3)$

Using this relationships you get that your limit is equal to $$lim_{x \rightarrow0} \frac{-x^3/2+o(x^3)}{x^3}$$
that goes to $-1/2$ as $x \rightarrow0 $

Comment: That was what exactly I first suggested , taylor expansion, but OP wants to solve this problem only by squeeze theorem !

Answer (score 0):

For small positive $x$,

$$0\le\cos x\le 1$$ and by definite integration in $[0,x]$,

$$0\le\sin x\le x.$$

Integrating again,

$$0\le 1-\cos x\le\frac{x^2}2$$

and

$$0\le x-\sin x\le\frac{x^3}6.$$

and

$$0\le\frac{x^2}2-1+\cos x\le\frac{x^4}{24}.$$

Similarly, from

$$6\le\frac6{(1-x)^4}\le12$$

integrating four times

$$-\frac{x^4}2\le\ln(1-x)+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3\le-\frac{x^4}4.$$

By combining these results, we have for the numerator

$$-\frac{x^3}2-ax^4\le n(x)\le-\frac{x^3}2+bx^4.$$

Comment: That integration could use some justification to show we must choose constant $0$ first and constant $1$ second and constant $-1$ third and so forth

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: you are right. I have added a short hint.